# What is the correct way to state which category is collecting an aggregate?

Tags: synonyms

I would like to know how can I say correctly an aggregation on a certain category, for example, let's say that I want to collect event data and display the amount of events for each user. Then, is it correct to say "I am aggregating events on a *per-user basis*"? 
Is it maybe more correct to say "I am aggregating events *per-user*?
Can the prefix *per-* be used for any possible category?
Am I maybe overusing it, while some other form might be preferred?

Comment: As Josh61 mentions, you can use _per_ as a preposition, but I wouldn't use it as a prefix in this case (so _per user_ instead of _per-user_).

Comment: ... user-by-user ?

Answer (score 2):

*Per* is a useful preposition to indicate different categories. As an alternative to *per user basis*, you can say *on a user basis*. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=per-user%20basis,%20per%20user%20basis,%20on%20a%20user%20basis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,per%20-%20user%20basis;,c0;.t1;,per%20user%20basis;,c0;.t1;,on%20a%20user%20basis;,c0)

Comment: thanks for your answer. *per* has to be used with or without dash?

Comment: Per-user basis is the most common form.

Comment: used without dash

Comment: Do people actually worry about whether what they write here is correct? A quick check on early Google hits for "per user basis" gives a ratio of open form to hyphenated form of 19 : 17, including one article using one of each. I'd use the hyphenated form because I think it scans better (and we want to steer clear of peruser basis). But the above two comments seem opinionated rather than warranted.

Comment: Hi Edwin, are you referring to the fact that I wrote that 'per-user' is more common than 'per user'?

Answer (score -1):

Per- as a prefix means throughly or intensely or completely as in perfect(per-fect), perplex(perplex) etc. So here use of per as prefix is not advisable or correct.

Comment: And this is the reason why the use of the word 'percentage' is 'not advisable or correct'. **???** Not only clearly wrong, but gets upvoted!

Comment: percentage comes from percent which means per-cent(shows completeness). I guess I am right on my reason.

Comment: From Online Etymology: percent: 1560s, per cent, from Modern Latin per centum " **by** the hundred" [bolding mine]. Stop guessing.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth So you recommend per as a prefix in this sentence is correct?

Comment: I'm addressing your unsatisfactory answer here (that's why I've posted as a comment underneath it); my other two comments here address OP's question. And answer your later question.